# Switch button becomes false again

Tags: javascript, react-native, switch-statement

After the switch button is true, it becomes false again when I close the page. When it's true, I want it to stay that way. How can I solve this? I also set the colors on other pages with isEnabled. But since it is false again, it returns to light mode.

```
    export const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = React.useState(false);
export const toggleSwitch = () => setIsEnabled(previousState => !previousState);


export function SettingsAccount(props) {
const { navigate } = props.navigation;

return(
  
  <SafeAreaView>
  <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress ={() => {navigationService.navigate('MyAccount', null);} 
          }>
              <Image style= {styles.imageSt} source={require('../../assets/arrow-left-circle.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style = {styles.textView}>
              <Text style = {styles.textStyle}>Uygulama Ayarları</Text>
            </View>
</View>
<View style={styles.SwitchStyle}>
      <Switch
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor={isEnabled ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
        value={isEnabled}
        
        
      />
</View>
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: isEnabled ? "green":"red", marginTop: 50}}>
    <Text>
      Deneme Buton
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
</SafeAreaView>
)}
```

Comment: Not sure if this would be the best way, but you could store the value in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and use that value when you open the page.

Comment: you should globally store the value using state management library such as recoil and redux

Comment: So how can I do this? I'm still at the stage of learning react native. Where should I add the code? Where I work doesn't use redux.

Comment: as @jesper suggested, you should store the enabled value in localStorage and trigger it whenever it changes. On Appstart you then initialize the enabled state with that stored value.